# Is there any google map lite mode option available for iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps

I am searching for lite mode map for iOS app in Google map sdk as its available in android google map sdk ([Android Google Map SDK Lite Mode Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/lite)). Or do we have alternate options to replicate lite mode map.

Comment: No there is no Lite Mode for iOS. Lite mode is just a static image, so you can use Static Map API https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/ and use JavaScript

Comment: Thanks Verma for your comments.

Comment: but the static map api doesn't have the option to open google maps when the user clicks it ... u can just disable the interaction on a regular and it will look the same

Comment: @iosMentalist: only difference is performance and how quick it loads

Comment: I will prefer save this static map image on your server and load it when required, rather than loading static map everytime.